# Investigating incoming IP connection Stripe webhook issues on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, stripe-payments, ip

I'm investigation some issues with Stripe webhooks not reaching our test server.
According to their docs they submit requests from the following IPs: https://stripe.com/docs/ips#webhook-notifications

I have added these IPs to the iptables:
[image]

I'm not an iptables expert, but looking at this it seems that it's only matching 54.187.216.72. Other requests from Stripe will fail with a timeout error, which I'm assuming are coming from other IPs.

[image]

I can see the only working IP in my apache logs. I think I can rule out ufw / firewall issues because I have tried to temporary disable that as well during testing.

My question: How do I investigate this issue further? Is my iptables setup correct? Is there anything else here that could block IPs other iptables and ufw?

Stripe could not tell me which IP was used on their requests.

I hope I'm providing the correct information here, if not please let me know!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe the linux and server community would have been better for this. You maybe should add those tags as well.

Comment: I think [sf] would be a better fit, but it seems lacking in details that make this a properly answerable question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you do not have information from network diagnostic tools and cannot get it. When you see in the Stripe dashboard a timeout error this cannot mean only that your server blocks incoming requests or does not respond. Such error messages are generated by the Stripe backend, not network tools. Where are the packets lost? Are they really lost? Quite possible that Stripe has strict time intervals to resolve Promises and just rejects them despite of result.

You can't run traceroute from their IPs. Those IPs doesn't respond to ping. You can talk to your hosting provider and get "no problem here" response. You can turn off the firewall and still have errors. I'm pretty sure your filter rules are not the root of this issue.

P.S.: We had the same one. Without any filtering rules our endpoint was accessible from around the world except those IPs. The problem appeared without making any changes in the configuration. The problem disappeared without any changes in the configuration. Neither Stripe nor the hosting provider had problems found.

Comment: Thanks. For future google searches: I have added more information here: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/uiuif8/investigating_incoming_ip_connection_issues_on/

I'm 100% sure that my hosting provider (Hostinger) is blocking the requests or has issues processing it. I have now setup a proxy server with Digitalocean as a super hacky workaround for this. I'm speaking with their support team atm.